# Ambiguity in Iterable interface and its implementation in Java

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, java-stream, iterable

Does Java `Iterator` interface enforce us to return a new Object when we call `next()` method on this interface? I went through the documentation and there was no Obligation for returning a new Object per each call, but it causes many ambiguities. It seems, that Hadoop mapreduce framework breaks some undocumented rule, that causes many problem in my simple program (including using Java8 Streams). It returns the same Object with different content when I call `next()` method on the`Iterator` (although it is against my imagination, it seems that it does not break the rule of `Iterator`, at least it seems that it does not break the documented rule of `Iterator` interface). I want to know why it happens? is it a mapreduce fault?  or is it Java fault for not documenting `Iterator` interface to return new instance on every call to `next()` method:

For the sake of simplicity and showing what is happening in hadoop mapreduce I write my own `Iterator` which is similar to what mapreduce is doing so you can understand what I'm getting at (so it is not a flawless program and might have many problems, but please focus on the concept that I'm trying to show).
Imagine I have the  following `Hospital` Entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Hospital {
    private AREA area;
    private int patients;

    public Hospital(AREA area, int patients) {
        this.area = area;
        this.patients = patients;
    }

    public Hospital() {
    }
}
```

For which I have Written following `MyCustomHospitalIterable`:

```
public class MyCustomHospitalIterable implements Iterable<Hospital> {

    private List<Hospital> internalList;
    private CustomHospitalIteration customIteration = new CustomHospitalIteration();

    public MyCustomHospitalIterable(List<Hospital> internalList) {
        this.internalList = internalList;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Hospital> iterator() {
        return customIteration;
    }

    public class CustomHospitalIteration implements Iterator<Hospital> {
        private int currentIndex = 0;
        private Hospital currentHospital = new Hospital();

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {

            if (MyCustomHospitalIterable.this.internalList.size() - 1 > currentIndex) {
                currentIndex++;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Hospital next() {
            Hospital hospital =
                    MyCustomHospitalIterable.this.internalList.get(currentIndex);
            currentHospital.setArea(hospital.getArea());
            currentHospital.setPatients(hospital.getPatients());
            return currentHospital;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, instead of returning new Object on next() method call, I return the same Object with different content. You might ask what is the advantage of doing this? It has its own advantage in mapreduce because in big data they don't want to create new Object for performance consideration. Does this break any documented rule of `Iterator` interface?

Now let's see some consequences of having implemented `Iterable` that way:
consider following simple program:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Hospital> hospitalArray = Arrays.asList(
                new Hospital(AREA.AREA1, 10),
                new Hospital(AREA.AREA2, 20),
                new Hospital(AREA.AREA3, 30),
                new Hospital(AREA.AREA1, 40));

        MyCustomHospitalIterable hospitalIterable = new MyCustomHospitalIterable(hospitalArray);
        List<Hospital> hospitalList = new LinkedList<>();
        Iterator<Hospital> hospitalIter = hospitalIterable.iterator();
        while (hospitalIter.hasNext()) {
            Hospital hospital = hospitalIter.next();
            System.out.println(hospital);
            hospitalList.add(hospital);
        }
        System.out.println("---------------------");
        System.out.println(hospitalList);
}
```

It is so unlogical and counterintuitive that the output of the program is as follow:

```
Hospital{area=AREA2, patients=20}
Hospital{area=AREA3, patients=30}
Hospital{area=AREA1, patients=40}
---------------------
[Hospital{area=AREA1, patients=40}, Hospital{area=AREA1, patients=40}, Hospital{area=AREA1, patients=40}]
```

And to make it worse imagine what happens when we are woking with `Streams` in Java. What would be the output of following program in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Hospital> hospitalArray = Arrays.asList(
                new Hospital(AREA.AREA1, 10),
                new Hospital(AREA.AREA2, 20),
                new Hospital(AREA.AREA3, 30),
                new Hospital(AREA.AREA1, 40));
        MyCustomHospitalIterable hospitalIterable = new MyCustomHospitalIterable(hospitalArray);
        Map<AREA, Integer> sortedHospital =
                StreamSupport.stream(hospitalIterable.spliterator(), false)
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                Hospital::getArea, Collectors.summingInt(Hospital::getPatients)));
        System.out.println(sortedHospital);
}
```

It depends we use parallel Stream or sequential one:
In seqentioal one output is as follow:

```
{AREA2=20, AREA1=40, AREA3=30}
```

and in parallel one it is:

```
{AREA1=120}
```

As a user I want to use interface as they are and don't have any concern about the implementations of that interface.

The problem is that here I know how `MyCustomHospitalIterable` is implemeted but in hadoop mapreduce I have to implement method like bellow and I have no idea where `Iterable<IntWritable>` came from and what is its implementation. I just want to use it as a pure `Iterable` interface but as I showed above it does not work as expected:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context
        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            List<IntWritable> list = new LinkedList<>();
            Iterator<IntWritable> iter = values.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                IntWritable count = iter.next();
                System.out.println(count);
                list.add(count);
            }
            System.out.println("---------------------");
            System.out.println(list);
}
```

Here is my question:
Why my simple program has broken?

1. Is it mapreduce fault to not implementing undocomented conventional rule of `Iterable` and `Iterator`(or there is documentation for this behavior which I haven't noticed)?
2. Or is it Java for not documenting `Iterable` and `Iterator` interface to return new Object on each call?
3. or it's my fault as a programmer?

Comment: Please, next time you ask something, pay more attention to you syntax and spelling.

Comment: I hope you can accept my apologies @GiorgiTsiklauri

Answer (score 1):

It is rather very unusual to return the same mutable object with different content for an Iterable. I did not find something in the java language reference; though not searched much. It is simple too error prone to be correct language usage.

You mention of other tools, like Streams, are apt.

Also the next java's *record type* is just intended for such tuple like usage, of course as multiple immutable objects. "Your" Iterable suffers from not being able to use in collections, unless on does a `.next().clone()` or such.

This weakness of Iterable is in the same category as having a mutable object as Map key. *It is deadly wrong.*

Comment: thanks for the answer but I came across this problem and it takes my time to understand what's happening behind the scene.I have just added reduce method that I have to use in mapreduce here I want to know who is doing somethig wrong? java? because they did not document it very well or mepareduce because they did not obey the rule and which rule? or it is my fault?

Comment: In my imagination iterator should not return the same object either but where is it documented to use to blame hadoop for this Iterable implementation @Joop Eggen

Comment: Probably some hadoop developer "optimized" their Iterable for not creating multiple objects. (Java however can cope with this.) Their _javadoc_ should contain a clear warning. This problem is more for a hadoop forum. Maybe better tag the question accordingly to reach hadoop people.

Comment: There is nothing in the specification of `Iterable`, because it doesn’t need to be there. Modifying an object that might be still in use somewhere, to represent a different object, is a fundamental design smell. It’s rather the opposite. If code using an iterator was not allowed to store the object somewhere, to use it after the next call of `next()`, the interface needed a documentation.

Comment: @Holger I know in `Java` some implementation of collection interfaces have modified the collection interfaces in some way. they decided not to introduce new interfaces for keeping an API concise. But me as a developer want to use an interface without reading the documentation of the implementation. Isn't it a Chaos letting every implementation change the behavior of the interface in such an ambiguous way and document it. this way we should read document for all implementation of the interface when we want to use it and it is clearly against interface purposes

Comment: Here you mean `hadoop` implemented `Iterable` in a wrong way? or they should have documented it in their implementation? or they should have not changed the API definition? @Holger

Comment: @tashkhisi can you name any example for your claim that there are collection implementations not adhering to the specification? Surely, if hadoop exhibits such a behavior, the minimum they should do, is to document it and the restrictions it imposes.

Comment: @Holger For instance  behavior of `add` operation depends on what implementation of collection you are using in some implementation they throw `UnsupportedOperationException` and the others work well so although it is documented in the Collection interface you should read the documentation of implementation for using the interface in a correct way.